# Spark submit on K8S does not wait for completion

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to submit a job to a k8s cluster in cluster-mode using a synchronous way (do not return until the end of the job).

Unfortunately the job ends after submission and I see this in the outputs:

```
ClientEndpoint: spark-submit not configured to wait for completion, exiting spark-submit JVM.
```

The documentation says:

> spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion
> defaut to true
> In cluster mode, whether to wait for the application to finish before
> exiting the launcher process. When changed to false, the launcher has
> a "fire-and-forget" behavior when launching the Spark job.

I have tried to add this option to the command line within a --conf and also in the conf/spark-defaults.conf  => same result

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Spark in standalone mode, try to add `--conf spark.standalone.submit.waitAppCompletion=true` option instead.

Source:

- [Error message](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/Client.scala#L186)
- [Config option](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/config/package.scala#L2199)